# Формула для движения элемента сдвинутого по оси Z за курсором

Tags: javascript

Как сделать вот здесь:

```js
const span = document.querySelector('span');
span.addEventListener('mousedown', move);

function move(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var target = e.currentTarget;
  var targetBox = target.getBoundingClientRect();
  var shiftX = e.pageX - targetBox.left;
  
  document.body.onmousemove = function(e) {
    target.style.left = e.pageX - shiftX + 'px';
  }

  document.body.onmouseup = function() {
    document.body.onmousemove = null;
    document.body.onmouseup = null;
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

div {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  perspective: 2000px;
}

span {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateZ(-2000px);
}
```

```html
<div>
<span></span>
</div>
```

Такое же точное следование за курсором как тут:

```js
var span = document.querySelector('span');
span.addEventListener('mousedown', move);

function move(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var target = e.currentTarget;
  var targetBox = target.getBoundingClientRect();
  var shiftX = e.pageX - targetBox.left;

  document.body.onmousemove = function(e) {
    target.style.left = e.pageX - shiftX + 'px';
  }

  document.body.onmouseup = function() {
    document.body.onmousemove = null;
    document.body.onmouseup = null;
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

div {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  perspective: 2000px;
}

span {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Не могу сообразить...

Answer (score 1):

Первый вариант

```js
const span = document.querySelector('span');
span.addEventListener('mousedown', move);
var wf = document.documentElement.clientWidth;

function move(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var target = e.currentTarget;
  var targetBox = target.getBoundingClientRect();
  var shiftX = (e.pageX - targetBox.left) * 2;
  
  document.body.onmousemove = function(e) {
    // расстояние до курсора мыши
    // минус расстояние от курсора мыши до левой стороны элемента
    // минус ширина экрана деленная на два
    target.style.left = e.pageX * 2 - shiftX - wf / 2 + 'px';
  }

  document.body.onmouseup = function() {
    document.body.onmousemove = null;
    document.body.onmouseup = null;
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

div {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  perspective: 2000px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

span {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateZ(-2000px);
}
```

```html
<div>
<span></span>
</div>
```

Второй вариант

```js
const article = document.querySelector('article');
article.addEventListener('mousedown', move);

function move(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (e.target.tagName !== 'SPAN') return;

  var target = e.currentTarget;
  var targetBox = target.getBoundingClientRect();
  var shiftX = e.pageX - targetBox.left;
  var shiftY = e.pageY - targetBox.top;

  document.body.onmousemove = function(e) {
    target.style.transform = `translateX(${e.pageX - shiftX}px) translateY(${e.pageY - shiftY}px)`;
  }

  document.body.onmouseup = function() {
    document.body.onmousemove = null;
    document.body.onmouseup = null;
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin:0
}

div {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

article {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  perspective: 2000px;
}

span {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  transform: translateZ(-2000px);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <article>
    <span></span>
  </article>
</div>
```

Comment: Если Вы еще ищете правильную формулу, её можно вывести, но математика Вам не понравится, я сходу не могу, надо садится за бумажку или код

Comment: @StrangerintheQ ясно. Я тогда 100% ничего не пойму. Но если вам интересно это делать, мне будет интересно посмотреть результат.

Comment: в целом необходимо применить ту же трансформацию к координатам курсора, тут можно сделать хак с невидимым элементом, или по честному: составить матрицу 3д трансформации, которую применяет по факту css 3d transform и применить ее к координатам мышки, а потом уже считать дельты

Comment: @StrangerintheQ про хак с невидимым элементом... об этом речь?(добавил второй вариант)

Comment: Я немного не об этом подумал, но так тоже вполне сработало =)